# Getting ElliFit ellipse fitting algorithm to work

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, curve-fitting

I have tried to implement the ellipse fitting algorithm descibed in the following paper: “ElliFit: An unconstrained, non-iterative, least squares
based geometric ellipse fitting method”, by Prasad, Leung, Quek. A free version can be downloaded online from http://azadproject.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/2013-ElliFit-A-non-constrainednon-iterative-least-squares-based-geometric-Ellipse-Fitting-method.pdf

The authors did not provide any publicly available implementation.

I have implemented the algorithm in Mathematica, I believe I have implemented it correctly, yet it fails to correctly find the fit parameters. The PDF of the experiment can be downloaded here: http://zvrba.net/downloads/ElliFit-fail-example.pdf

Did somebody else try to implement this particular algorithm and, if yes, what is the key to get it working? Is there a "bug" in the paper? Can somebody take another look at my implementation and see whether there's a bug there?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been almost a year since this question, but it seems that the authors have now provided public source code for ElliFit, both a MATLAB version and an OpenCV version.

Both are available on the the [author's homepage](https://sites.google.com/site/dilipprasad/Source-codes). In case the homepage goes offline for some reason, both source codes are shared on Google and are available [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B10RxHxW3I92WEVMRk1fUzBuaXc/edit) (MATLAB) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10RxHxW3I92UG5DWjRVd294SWdUZDlCem5OSkRwU21jSHBv/view?usp=sharing) (OpenCV).

At the time of writing, I have not personally tested their code, but am planning to use them for a project. I will post any updates here in the next few days.

**EDIT:**

I got around to test the code sooner than I expected. I gave the OpenCV code a try. It works pretty well, as demonstrated by the image below (ignore the "almost-closed-ellipses". It's an artifact caused by something else in my code).

[image: ElliFit Demo]

As you can see, it works pretty well, most of the times. There are some failure cases too (the small ellipse on the spray bottle next to the cup).